# Function not giving normal output

Tags: c, function

I am trying to compile my practice on functions. I tried many times to compile this and I bumped into this issue.

Here below is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int displayFlow();
int main(){
    int displayFlow();
   
}
int displayFlow(){

int try1,try2,try3;
printf("enter any given number...\n");
scanf("%d", &try1);
printf("if u entered above 10, ur out\n...please enter another guess...\n");
scanf("%d", &try2);
printf("if u entered below 5 then u won! !");


}
```

and this is the output I got:

```
function.c:22:5: note: declared here
 int test(){
```

Comment: Look at how you're calling `printf` and `scanf`, an then look at how you're calling `displayFlow`.  Notice a difference?

Comment: That error cannot possibly be coming from the *posted* code. It is only 17 lines long, and that error message references line 22. Also, there is no `test(){` anywhere in this source code.

Comment: `and this is the output i got:` just to be clear, that isn't output of your program, it's the compiler issuing a warning or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your function again inside main. Remove int from infront of displayFlow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int displayFlow();
int main(){
    displayFlow();

}
int displayFlow(){

int try1,try2,try3;
printf("enter any given number...\n");
scanf("%d", &try1);
printf("if u entered above 10, ur out\n...please enter another guess...\n");
scanf("%d", &try2);
printf("if u entered below 5 then u won! !");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I come up with another mistake:you define the function displayFlow as 'int' type,but you don't write 'return' in the function when you realize it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int displayFlow();
int main(){
    displayFlow(); //you just abandon the return value?

}
int displayFlow(){

int try1,try2,try3;
printf("enter any given number...\n");
scanf("%d", &try1);
printf("if u entered above 10, ur out\n...please enter another guess...\n");
scanf("%d", &try2);
printf("if u entered below 5 then u won! !");
//Here is something absent. What do you want to return ? or you just want to return nothing? if so, you should modify the function return value type to 'void',please.
//return ??;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set return in method main, because he has to return `int`

```
int main() {
return displayFlow();

}
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: thanks too much, just my english so bad 